# Parallax mapping with shadow maps and decals in deferred rendering

Tags: opengl

I have a problem with my deferred renderer and parallax mapping.  It works fine with the normal geometry -> lighting stages, but I'm not sure how I would apply the parallax depth to the screenspace decals or shadow mapping.

My gbuffer stores two texture attachments.
1) diffuse map (rgb) + specular map (alpha channel).
2) normal map (rgb).

I reconstruct world position with depth buffer and inverse view matrix.

The problem is that the normal mapping calculations that get sent to the gbuffer attachments are done in the geometry (first step) pass (the TBN calculations etc), but I don't know to apply that data to the shadow mapping (done during lighting pass) or the decal step (just before lighting).

I was thinking that I could possibly do something when I reconstruct the world position from the depth map, but am at a loss as to how to do that, or if it is even the right approach.

I could possibly merge the geometry and decal pass together if I pre-rendered the depth from the geometry pass first (decals needs complete depth buffer), so I could calculate them together. I don't like the idea of doing that and it obviously won't work with shadows maps which are applied during lighting.

Comment: For clarification: By parallax mapping, you mean the approach to offset the UV coordinates by the view vector (in tangent space) multiplied by the height of that location, right? This is a pretty heuristical approach and I am not sure if there is a good way to incorporate shadow mapping. Could you show some example surfaces? It might be enough to create something that looks correct. For the decaling part: In principle, you should displace the decal UV in the same way as you displace the surface UV. How you do this depends on your actual decal implementation.

Comment: Hi, the decal approach is wip.  For splatter I can just write to the diffuse gbuffer and leave the normal gbuffer untouched.  This will give a nice effect, but if I need the decal to have its own normal map I will have to overwrite, and like you say, mimic the surface approach.  Mixing the two normal maps would require read/write and I'm not sure if that's legal.  Shadows seem like a more difficult problem, but I decided to multiply the shadow result with the lightFactor ( dot(normal, lightDir) ).  It looks better so long as the shadow is meant to have  some transparency.